# Will my source code be lost once Team Foundation Service Preview comes out of preview?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Does anyone know if I put some source code on "Team Foundation Service Preview" (tfspreview.com: tfs on the cloud) 
will all source code be lost once the program is outside of the preview stage?

Im intent on purchasing once its live, just seeing if its feasible to start using now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't the 'commercial' path for the service yet. But if we are going to charge you for the service, we will make sure that there is a path to move your data from the cloud into you on premises TFS installation

Ewald Hofman (TFS Program Manager)

Comment: thanks, altho you have only answered part of the question. So there wont be a path to move from the TFS service preview to the TFS service (live) ? We don't want to move back to a on premises TFS installation, we would like to keep our source code on the cloud.

Comment: We will make sure that there is a path from preview to live. We are continuously improving the service (we deploy every three weeks - keep an eye on the blogs of Brian Harry), and most likely the preview will evolve into the live service eventually.

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't lose anything, you will have two possibilities:

1. Pay for the service and keep things has they are.
2. Get a back to the Team Project Collection for you to restore it on a local (on premise) TFS Server.

Comment: This is untrue at the time.  Microsoft and the TFS team hasn't said anything about if/when they will charge for the service.  If we start charging, it is possible there will still be a free option.

Comment: You can remove the -1 you gave and look to the answer of Ewald, it is totally true as Brian Harry talked about it in his blog and during the last MVP Summit...

Comment: Hi Nock, there is one key difference between your response and Ewald's.  Your response suggests that once a pricing model is introduced that you will either have to pay or export your data.  This answer suggests that there is no option for a free repository which certainly could be part of the pricing model that TFS is working on.  As Brian mentions in his blog here: http://tinyurl.com/6vo4p3p TFS has not disclosed anything about the pricing model.  If you can link to a source that says there will be no free accounts or update your comment, I'd be glad to remove the downvote.

Comment: I talked about "paying" simply because Marty's intent was "to purchase once its live"... So I never said it won't be free and that wasn't the purpose of the question.
So cut the lawyer stuff please, the true intent of the question wasn't about will TFS Services be free or not, but will I be able to keep my data or not. And the right answer is the one I gave.

Comment: I've got no problem removing the downvote since we now have enough clarification here. I am not trying to be overly pedantic or do "lawyer stuff". As an MVP, people will believe what you say about TFS because you have inside information. Your post here states that when TFS comes out of preview you can either choose to pay or leave, which simply isn't true.  I'd still prefer if you updated your answer to include that information.

Comment: I tried to remove the downvote but SO won't let me unless the answer is edited since it has been up there for a day...